# Where does Cloudera Manager get the --hostname value for Impala commands?

Tags: hadoop, centos, cloudera, impala

I am working through the process for activating Kerberos on the Cloudera quick-start VM.  The vm begins life with hostname = "quickstart.cloudera" but I had to change it to get it into our local DNS consistently.  After changing the name I was able to get everything except impala to come up.  The manager is passing it --hostname=quickstart.cloudera even though everything else in the whole system knows the new name.  I don't strictly have to have impala running for the tests I need to run but it's driving me nuts.  Any clues?

Comment: What commands are you talking about?

Comment: The crazy-long logs that get posted about hadoop problems make me want to drink heavily.  But here goes.  The first few lines of /var/log/catalogd/catalogd.INFO following issuing the start command in the web console ...

Comment: (omitting some lines for character limit)
2:21:47.121 PM INFO init.cc:132 
catalogd version 2.1.0-cdh5 RELEASE (build e48c2b48c53ea9601b8f47a39373aa83ff7ca6e2)
Built on Tue, 16 Dec 2014 19:25:34 PST
2:21:47.121 PM INFO init.cc:133 
Using hostname: quickstart.cloudera
2:21:47.122 PM INFO logging.cc:138 
Flags (see also /varz are on debug webserver):
--catalog_service_port=26000
--load_catalog_in_background=true
--num_metadata_loading_threads=16
--enable_process_lifetime_heap_profiling=false
--heap_profile_dir=
**--hostname=quickstart.cloudera**
--keytab_file=
--krb5_conf=

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at a relatively fresh install of CM 5.3 with Impala 2.1 and I don't see the hostname being passed to the catalog server via cmdline flags.

Unless you're explicitly setting the hostname parameter in CM via a safety-valve configuration (I assume you're not doing this), then Impala gets the hostname to use by calling the `gethostname()` stdlib function (see [the gethostname() man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gethostname.2.html)). The log output snipped you showed is somewhat deceiving because when the flag isn't set, Impala actually sets that value manually and it shows up as if it were passed by the user.

Anyway, you should check that the hostname is properly changed on the box,
which may depend on your OS. A few things to try: check the `hostname` command returns the name you expect and that you've restarted the OS.

Comment: I tried using the safety valve, it adds the corrected hostname to a flags file in the /var/run directory and passes that file among the command-line arguments, AFTER the incorrect one.  Yeah, I had to go through all the gethostname() stuff to get almost everything working.  It was a christmas tree of mostly red lights at first.  I read through some of the init.cc source code but did not see that it would inject the hostname into the reported argument list, that's tricky!  Still, it has to be coming from somewhere and it's not DHCP, /etc/hosts, or anywhere else in /etc.  Thanks for the tip!